# NuxtJs spontaneously stopped working with fs errors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, fsevents

So here I was working away on my NuxtJS SPA and after a page refresh, I started getting these errors. I have no clue where this comes from I did not change anything that could cause it. I tried everything including npm fixing and reinstalling the projects node_modules. Nothing works. What the hell is this? Even if I do what npm suggests, nothing works. Anyone knows what this is about?

[image: more errors]
[more errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0oSV.png)

Comment: Probably you upgraded your nodejs. Run `node -v` to see the current version

Comment: Hmm I do have v17.3.0 I assume it needs to be 18? The thing is though I have no clue  how it could just stop working when I did not update anything @_@

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov I just tried to upgrade it further and did not fix that. Iwill try to downgrade it

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov v16, v17, and v18 all the same issue, I didn't change the version. I was just working and it broke for no reason.

Comment: did you try installing the packages mentioned in the error log ?

Comment: Yup as mentioned in the post, tried to follow all suggestions with no luck sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I accidentally accepted the IDE suggestion for a code fix and I did not notice that. The IDE imported a random library that broke everything.

So apart from removing that the solution is to commit often and using git bisect to find the problem.